# Uniting multiple rows in R data frame into one row

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable, row, redundancy

I have an R data frame with many zeros in it. It basically looks like this:

| Year | Gender | BMW | VW | Mercedes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 | Male | Max | 0 | 0 |
| 2019 | Male | Peter | 0 | 0 |
| 2019 | Male | 0 | Peter | 0 |
| 2019 | Male | 0 | 0 | Peter |

One line in this table represents one customer per year. Each customer can have 0, 1 or multiple cars (from different manufacturers)...

Now, I would like to make the table more compact. In fact, I want to melt the last three rows down to just one row. Since Peter has all three cars AND all of his cars are registered in the same year, one entry for Peter looking like this should be enough:

| Year | Gender | BMW | VW | Mercedes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | Male | Peter | Peter | Peter |

Finally, the output should look like this:

| Year | Gender | BMW | VW | Mercedes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 | Male | Max | 0 | 0 |
| 2019 | Male | Peter | Peter | Peter |

How can I make this happen?
I want ONE ROW per PERSON and YEAR!

Comment: Please be mindful of tags, this has nothing to do with the [tag:rstudio] IDE.

Comment: @RonakShah No, I want to keep all users. I just want one row per user and year. If they have no cars at all, that's also fine. Then they would get a row with zeros only. I just don't want multiple rows for the same person in the same year, since this makes the table unnecessarily big.

Comment: @RonakShah I explicitly wrote that I want "one entry for Peter looking like...", so I don't want to delete or change any other entry/person.
However, your answer has already helped me a lot. I am going to try it out and get back to you...

Comment: @RonakShah, I think the key comment is *"one entry for Peter looking like this"*, to me this means that the three Peter rows are combined into one. To me, that does not imply removal of `Max`, just that the `Max` row was not explicitly included in that output. I agree that in this example it would be super-clearer to just include that one row in addition to Peter, but I think I interpreted it the way the OP intended.

Comment: @r2evans Exactly, you got it right. I was indeed a bit lazy, I will add it to the output now to make it clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each value of `Year` and `Gender` you can select the first non 0 value in each column.

```
library(dplyr)

res <- df %>%
  group_by(Year, Gender) %>%
  summarise(across(.fns = ~.[. != 0][1])) %>%
  ungroup()

res

#  Year Gender BMW   VW    Mercedes
#  <int> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>   
#1  2018 Male   Max   NA    NA      
#2  2019 Male   Peter Peter Peter
```

If you want to drop rows that have any `NA` row you can extend the answer as

```
res %>% filter(if_all(BMW:Mercedes, Negate(is.na)))

#  Year Gender BMW   VW    Mercedes
#  <int> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>   
#1  2019 Male   Peter Peter Peter
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Year = c(2018L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L), Gender = c("Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male"), BMW = c("Max", "Peter", "0", "0"), VW = c("0", 
"0", "Peter", "0"), Mercedes = c("0", "0", "0", "Peter")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 2):

(Partial answer)

Once you turned the 0 as NA (edit: to make that change: `data[data == 0] <- NA`), you can do:

```
data %>% 
  group_by(Year, Gender) %>% 
  summarise_all(na.omit)
```

But this only works well if you have only one consumer per year, which is the case here, but probably not with all the data. You should consider having an Id column or something before you merge rows by Year.

Comment: Hi, 
thank you very much for your effort.
Unfortunately, I have multiple users per year. I want to keep all users, no matter if they have zeros everywhere, just one car or all three of them. But if they have two or three cars, I want just one row for this user...

Comment: Ok, I will try to seek for a better solution then.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the data "grouped" by gender and year, I propose reshaping on those variables, filtering out what you don't want, then reshaping back to wide.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_*
dat %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Year, Gender), values_to = "value") %>%
  filter(value != "0") %>%
  pivot_wider(c(Year, Gender), names_from = name, values_from = value)
# # A tibble: 2 x 5
#    Year Gender BMW   VW    Mercedes
#   <int> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>   
# 1  2018 Male   Max   <NA>  <NA>    
# 2  2019 Male   Peter Peter Peter
```

This runs into issues if there are duplicate year/gender/names. For instance,

```r
bind_rows(dat, dat[3,])
#   Year Gender   BMW    VW Mercedes
# 1 2018   Male   Max     0        0
# 2 2019   Male Peter     0        0
# 3 2019   Male     0 Peter        0
# 4 2019   Male     0     0    Peter
# 5 2019   Male     0 Peter        0
bind_rows(dat, dat[3,]) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Year, Gender), values_to = "value") %>%
  filter(value != "0") %>%
  pivot_wider(c(Year, Gender), names_from = name, values_from = value)
# Warning: Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
# * Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
# * Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
# * Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates
# # A tibble: 2 x 5
#    Year Gender BMW       VW        Mercedes 
#   <int> <chr>  <list>    <list>    <list>   
# 1  2018 Male   <chr [1]> <NULL>    <NULL>   
# 2  2019 Male   <chr [1]> <chr [2]> <chr [1]>
```

In this case, if you would want to remove perfect duplicates then you can do this:

```r
bind_rows(dat, dat[3,]) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Year, Gender), values_to = "value") %>%
  filter(value != "0", !duplicated(.)) %>%                     # updated
  pivot_wider(c(Year, Gender), names_from = name, values_from = value)
# # A tibble: 2 x 5
#    Year Gender BMW   VW    Mercedes
#   <int> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>   
# 1  2018 Male   Max   <NA>  <NA>    
# 2  2019 Male   Peter Peter Peter
```

though does admittedly "loses" the fact that Peter listed a VW twice ... which might be two different VWs. A hackish fix if you want/need to keep this information is

```r
bind_rows(dat, dat[3,]) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Year, Gender), values_to = "value") %>%
  filter(value != "0") %>%
  group_by(Year, Gender, name, value) %>%
  mutate(name = paste0(name, replace(seq_along(name), 1, ""))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(c(Year, Gender), names_from = name, values_from = value)
# # A tibble: 2 x 6
#    Year Gender BMW   VW    Mercedes VW2  
#   <int> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr>
# 1  2018 Male   Max   <NA>  <NA>     <NA> 
# 2  2019 Male   Peter Peter Peter    Peter
```

(or a similar way of communicating "2nd VW" unambiguously without affecting other cars).

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(Year = c(2018L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L), Gender = c("Male", "Male", "Male", "Male"), BMW = c("Max", "Peter", "0", "0"), VW = c("0", "0", "Peter", "0"), Mercedes = c("0", "0", "0", "Peter")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```